# How to Load More Data with Button?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a load more button and I got it mostly right where it's taking the entire length of the array and slicing it by the number of posts per page. However, When I invoke the function that adds more data onto the current array it puts it as an object and I'm not sure why. I have a ton of code so I'll only be showing parts of the problem I'm stuck on.

Here is my code.

```js
import React from 'react';

class Blogtopics extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      blogData: [],
      testData: [],
      postsPerPage: 6,
    };
  }

   loopwithSlice = (start, end) => {
     let slicedblogData = [];

     let slicedTopics = this.state.blogData.slice(start, end);
     slicedblogData = [...slicedblogData, ...slicedTopics];

      this.setState({
        testData: slicedblogData,
      });

      console.log('slice function', this.state.testData);
   };

  handleShowMorePosts = () => {
    console.log('clicked more', this.state.testData);

    this.loopwithSlice(
      this.state.testData,
      this.state.testData + this.state.postsPerPage
    );
    console.log('clicked more 2', this.state.testData);
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.userData();
    await this.Selectblogtopics();

    this.loopwithSlice(0, this.state.postsPerPage);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='fluid-container'>
        <div className='blogContainer'>
          <div className='container'>
            <div className='blogContent'>
              {this.state.blogData.map((rows, index) => (
                // I map over my data inside this block
              ))}
              <div className='loadMore mt-3 text-center'>
                <button
                  className='btn btn-secondary btn-lg'
                  onClick={() => this.handleShowMorePosts()}
                >
                  Load More
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Blogtopics;
```

Example of the data

[image]

Data when I successfully sliced it.

[image]

Data when I invoke `handleShowMorePosts` function and it returns new array as follows

Data of blogData and testData when function is on componentdidmount

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are calling `loopwithSlice` with an array as the first argument, and adding an array with a number as the 2nd argument. Can you post an example blogData and testData?

Comment: You want to see what the data for blogData and testData look like correct? in the state?

Comment: Yes, the ones in the state

Comment: Added it in the post.

Comment: then my question still remains, you are calling `let slicedTopics = this.state.blogData.slice(start, end);` where `start` and `end` are arrays?

Comment: start is the beginning of the array for blogData so I believe it starts at 0 of the array and the end ends it at the array. which returns me with a new array for testData which is 6. However, what I'm stuck on is when I go to add additional posts onto the array, its returning me the object instead of the extra posts on the array.

Comment: In your code you are calling it with `this.loopwithSlice(this.state.testData, this.state.testData + this.state.postsPerPage);` and subsequently calling `Array.slice` with `Array` and `Array + Number`. Slice takes 2 numbers as the index for start and end.